# WebDriverWait will wait until timeout even when succeding

Tags: c#, selenium, exception, nosuchelementexception

I am scratching my head at the problem I am having.

I have defined the following method:

```
private static void WaitSpinner(By locator)
{
    wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);
    wait.Message = "El spinner ha tardado demasiado en desaparecer";

    wait.Until(driver =>
    {
        try
        {
            IWebElement spinner = driver.FindElement(locator);

            if (spinner.Displayed) { return false; }
            else { return true; }
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

However, two things are happening that I don't understand:

1. Method will wait until timeout even if it succedes
2. NoSuchElementException will be reported to `ExceptionThrown` event, even if it is being caught by the method.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: `ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated()` behaves exactly the same

Comment: So You are getting always one result, ie. Both  your method and ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated() wait till max timeout and throw no such element exception at end . Right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Both of them behave exactly the same.

Comment: Are you sure the locator is good? I'm wondering if you aren't looking at a different element than the spinner and it's always there/visible. Check your locator using Chrome devtools and make sure that it's unique.

Comment: Also, how do you know it's succeeding?

Answer (score 0):

your code seems good. Make sure that the locator you pass is correct.

1. Open dev tool in chrome using following command

   > CTRL + SHIFT+ i
2. Verify xpath(locator) of spinner is exact same as you pass in code.
3. Also observe the behavior of spinner in chrome dev tool. Change in xpath when it is hidden and when it appears again.